# MVC wrapper and regular JavaScript Kendo grid together

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

So I was trying to bind a complex object , a list, to the detail grid of the the Kendo grid. I understand that you can not do that, so what I did was grab the data and turn it into a JSON and use that as a data source for this grid I created. The grid is created like this

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model).Name("Access")
  .Columns(columns =>
  {
   columns.Bound("ProjId").Width(220).Title("Project #");       
  }) 
  //I tried      
  .DetailTemplate("<div id=DetailTemplate'></div>")  
  // I also tried
  .ClientDetailTemplateId("<div id=DetailTemplate'></div>") 
  .Selectable()  
  .Events(events => events.DetailInit("initDetailGrid"))                                        
  .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .ServerOperation(false)                
   )
)
```

I then have this in my script

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function initDetailGrid(e) {       
    //Hide the grid header
    $(".k-grid tbody .k-grid .k-grid-header").hide();

   var grid = e.sender; 
   //Get the data from the selected record             
   var currentDataItem = grid.dataItem(grid.select()); 
    var newJsonObject = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < currentDataItem.taskId.length; i++) {
        var taskId = currentDataItem.taskId[i];
        newJsonObject.push({
            Id: objId,
            Interval: currentDataItem.InternalExternal[taskId],
           ....
        });
    }

    $("#DetailTemplate").kendoGrid({
        columns: [
            {field:"taskId", template:..stuff..},
            {field: "Interval", template: .. stuff..}                    
        ],           
        dataSource: newJsonObject
    });
}
</script>
```

So basically I want to use the `$("#DetailTemplate")` as the detail grid for the row but it not working and I do not know how to approach it.

**EDIT**

What I am trying to do is create a Kendo UI grid, via javascript, to use as the detail template for the parent Grid, which is created using the ASP-MVC helper.

Answer (score 0):

It is not getting clear what you are trying to achieve. Did you check the hierarchy demo [here](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/hierarchy.html)?

Basically all you need to replace inside of it is to fill the dataSource directly instead of using transport configuration.

```
function detailInit(e) {
                    $("<div/>").appendTo(e.detailCell).kendoGrid({
                        dataSource: {
                              //via the data option of the dataSource
                            data: e.data.NestedArrayFeild
                        },
                        scrollable: false,
                        sortable: true,
                        pageable: true,
                        columns: [
                            { field: "OrderID", width: "70px" },
                            { field: "ShipCountry", title:"Ship Country", width: "110px" },
                            { field: "ShipAddress", title:"Ship Address" },
                            { field: "ShipName", title: "Ship Name", width: "200px" }
                        ]
                    });
                }
```

Comment: I see that my question was not clear. I will edit it to be more clear.